# How to stop my advertspace div from disappearing when hosted? Hosting locally its fine but when I upload it to my website the div disappears?

Tags: html, css, web-hosting

I have build a basic website which includes in the body three sections, the website logo, the advert space and the games section of the page. It looks great when I open it on my desktop but when I host it online the advertspace div disappears.

I have tried rearranging the parts into sections and using breaks between the divs but nothing is working.

This is the HTML code for the site:

```
<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">    

<section>

        <div id="pageheader">
            <div id="logobling"><img src="images/LogoBling.jpg"/></a></div>
            <div id="sitelogo"><img src="images/Sitelogo.png"/></a></div>
        </div>

</section>        

<section>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="advertspace"><p class="getme">Advertise here</p></div>
    </div>

</section>

<section>

    <div id="container">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Administrator's Picks</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="games">
                        <a href="curveballthegame"><img src="images/Curveball.png" class="games"/>
                        <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="text"><span>Curve Ball</span></div></div></div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div class="games">
                        <a href="adrenalinechallenge"><img src="images/AdrenalineChallenge.jpg" class="games"/>
                        <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="text"><span>Adrenaline Challenge</span></div></div></div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div class="games">
                        <a href="bubbletrouble"><img src="images/BubbleTrouble.png" class="games"/>
                        <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="text"><span>Bubble Trouble</span></div></div></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

</section>      

    </div>
    </body>
  <footer>
    <div id="page-wrap">
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #A9A9A9
    }

#page-wrap {
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }

#container {
    position: static;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    }

#advertspace {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

#pageheader {
    position: relative;
    width: 99.6%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;                  /* using a flexbox here */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: grey;
    border-bottom: white;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    }



h1  {
    display: block;
    }

#logobling {
    position: relative;
    right: 30px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;                  /* using a flexbox here */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    }

#sitelogo {
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;                  /* using a flexbox here */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

The difference when hosted locally [image]

And when hosted on various hosting packages (yes I have tried different hosts to see if they were the problem)
[image]

I hope someone here can help I have not been able to fix this issue for a long time.

Sorry if this looks like I have copied and pasted a lot of code I am just trying to include everything that could be relevant!

Comment: On html there are errors, you have body closed before the footer, and footer isn't closed.
As a hint, try inspect #advertspace and see if the css is loaded or the text is inside.

Comment: Paulie_D goddam you! why did I not see that :@ If you put the answer in Ill give you an upvote you deserve it

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you ensure that you make sure your Adblocker is turned off?

```
 #advertspace
```

Would be an obvious trigger.